# Can someone give an encryption/decryption example with OpenSSL AES CCM?

Tags: openssl, aes

I'm looking for an example of using OpenSSL's AES CCM encryption. Apparently, this is one of the two 'custom' cipher modes that require additional setup beyond EVP_CipherInit_ex(). Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know OpenSSL, but I think you mainly need to set the initialization vector.

Comment: The initialization vector is always and argument for EVP_CipherInit_ex(), so that's already there. It seems like I can set special parameters using EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(), but they're not having any effect.

Comment: The [official manual page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_EncryptInit.html) says "EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl() allows various cipher specific parameters to be determined and set. Currently only the RC2 effective key length and the number of rounds of RC5 can be set." It doesn't say anything about CCM (CTR+CBC-MAC), though.

Comment: Well, I should mention that CCM mode is only implemented in the 1.0.1 snapshot. That also includes other #defines for EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl, but they don't seem to affect anything. I should probably bring this up with their mailing list, and report back if I find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short:

```
// Tell the alg we will encrypt Psize bytes
int outl = 0;
EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, 0, &outl, 0, Psize);

// Add the AAD
EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, 0, &outl, A, Asize);

// Now we encrypt the data in P, placing the output in CT
EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, CT, &outl, P, Psize);
```

For more details, please see my blog post on this, http://www.fredriks.se/?p=23.

Comment: Is this available with 1.0.1 or will it only be 'official' with 1.1.0?

Comment: This is available in 1.0.1, see evp.h.

Answer (score 1):

To look at a complete simple AES CCM encrypt/decrypt example that uses some NIST data I strongly suggest to visit the OpenSSL Github Demos repository, here:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/demos/evp/aesccm.c

The example is working well, with comments and debugging output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for encryption and decryption with OpenSSL CCM-AES-128

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <openssl/evp.h>

    void str2hex(char *, char*, int);
    void printBytes(unsigned char *, size_t );


    int main() {

        unsigned char *aad, *pt, *key, *nonce;
        int Klen, Alen, Nlen, Plen, Tlen, Clen;
        int outl = 0;

        key = "5a33980e71e7d67fd6cf171454dc96e5";
        aad = "eca622a37570df619e10ebb18bebadb2f2b49c4d2b2ff715873bb672e30fc0ff";
        nonce = "33ae68ebb8010c6b3da6b9cb29";
        pt = "a34dfa24847c365291ce1b54bcf8d9a75d861e5133cc3a74";

        Klen = strlen(key) / 2;
        Alen = strlen(aad) / 2;
        Nlen = strlen(nonce) / 2;
        Plen = strlen(pt) / 2;
        Tlen = 16;
        Clen = Plen + Tlen;

        unsigned char keyy[Klen], aadd[Alen], noncee[Nlen], ptt[Plen];
        unsigned char ct[Clen], dt[Plen];

        str2hex(key, keyy, Klen);
        str2hex(pt, ptt, Plen);
        str2hex(aad, aadd, Alen);
        str2hex(nonce, noncee, Nlen);

        EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(ctx);
        EVP_EncryptInit(ctx, EVP_aes_128_ccm(), 0, 0);
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_CCM_SET_IVLEN, Nlen, 0);
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_CCM_SET_TAG, Tlen, 0);
        EVP_EncryptInit(ctx, 0, keyy, noncee);
        EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, 0, &outl, 0, Plen);
        EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, 0, &outl, aadd, Alen);
        EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ct, &outl, ptt, Plen);
        EVP_EncryptFinal(ctx, &ct[outl], &outl);
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_CCM_GET_TAG, Tlen, ct + Plen);

        printf("plaintext' = %s", pt);
        // printf("\nciphertext' = 7a60fa7ee8859e283cce378fb6b95522ab8b70efcdb0265f7c4b4fa597666b86dd1353e400f28864");
        printf("\n");

        printf("\nciphertext : ");
        printBytes(ct, Clen);

        EVP_DecryptInit(ctx, EVP_aes_128_ccm(), 0, 0);
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_CCM_SET_IVLEN, Nlen, 0);
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_CCM_SET_TAG, Tlen, ct + Plen);
        EVP_DecryptInit(ctx, 0, keyy, noncee);
        EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, 0, &outl, 0, Plen);
        EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, 0, &outl, aadd, Alen);
        EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, dt, &outl, ct, Plen);
        EVP_DecryptFinal(ctx, &dt[outl], &outl);
        printf("plaintext : ");
        printBytes(dt, Plen);

        return 0;
    }

    void str2hex(char *str, char *hex, int len) {
        int tt, ss;
        unsigned char temp[4];
        for (tt = 0, ss = 0; tt < len, ss < 2 * len; tt++, ss += 2) {
            temp[0] = '0';
            temp[1] = 'x';
            temp[2] = str[ss];
            temp[3] = str[ss + 1];

            hex[tt] = (int) strtol(temp, NULL, 0);
        }
    }

    void printBytes(unsigned char *buf, size_t len) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            printf("%02x", buf[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```